# Is there a term for fitting a nonlinear relationship with a linear model?

Tags: regression, terminology

This is a basic question, but I was writing up some results and wasn't sure what terminology to use.

People seem to use the term "linear model" to describe what I would call "linear regression",
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \dots + \beta_p x_p + \epsilon_i.$$

I have the habit of referring to a linear model as anything linear in the  *parameters*. This would be called a [general linear model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_model) and would include anything of the form $\mathbf{Y = X B + U}$. This includes a variety of models that describe nonlinear relationships like [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression), [generalized additive models (GAMs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model), or regression with splines.

On the other hand, there are "nonlinear models" which are nonlinear functions of the parameters. For example, $\frac{\beta_1x}{\beta_2 + x}$.

Is there nomenclature that refers to models that describe nonlinear relationships but are still general linear models of the form $Y = XB + U$ which excludes models describing nonlinear relationships which are also nonlinear in the parameters?

Comment: I think you are confusing terms being linear in $x$ with linearity of terms. A polynomial regression is a linear model and is often taught a few weeks after introducing simple linear regression. Having terms like $x^4$ or $e^x$ is linear so long as these are multiplied by betas and added to get the predictor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Chris Bishop (machine-learning guru) has a chapter on these, called **Linear Basis Function Models**. Hyphenating properly it would be "linear basis-function models", to avoid any confusion -- the basis functions themselves are generally *non*linear.

In other words, these models are linear in the parameters, as you want, but the basis functions can be nonlinear. See Chapter 3 of his *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*, 2006.

Comment: That's exactly the distinction I was making. Thank you.